# Angular 6 Reactive Forms- How to populate one text field based on the selection of another input

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 6 and reactive forms, and I am trying to get the selection of one field to auto-populate the field of another.

The goal: If you select the number '1' from the 'select' menu, the coefficient input will auto-populate to ".15". Selecting '2' will == ".175", and selecting "3" will equal ".2".

What is the best method to achieve this? Thanks so much!

**Here is my form:**

```
<form name="form" class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="createForm.form.valid && createNewMonitoringPoint()" #createForm="ngForm" novalidate>

 <select class="col-md-12 form-control" [(ngModel)]="newmp.number"
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': createForm.submitted && newmp.number.invalid }" 
    required name="number">

    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>

 </select>

 <p>Pipe Roughness Coefficient (n) </p>
 <input type="coefficient" id="coefficient" 
    #coeffcient="ngModel" name="coefficient [(ngModel)]="newmp.coefficient" 
    class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. .016" />

 <button type="submit" value="Create">Create</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using template form not reactive form. All you need is `(change)` method on the select form as:

```
<select (change)="selected()">...</select>
```

And Logic:

```
selected() {
  if (this.newmp.number === 1) {
    this.newmp.coefficient = .15;
  } else if (this.newmp.number === 2) {
    this.newmp.coefficient = .175;
  } else if (this.newmp.number === 3) {
    this.newmp.coefficient = .2;
  }
}
```

**Explanation**: You are using two-way data binding with inputs using `[(ngModel)]`. Change in the model reflects the input value and vice versa. Once the data is changed in the select the `change()` event triggers and call the method `select()` or whatever you name it. You don't need to pass values as the `this.newmp.number` holds the new value and you do your logic and assign the value for your input through `this.newmp.coefficient`. Again, since it's two-way data binding, the value changes to `this.newmp.coefficient` in logic automatically reflects the value of the input in the HTML template.